# Как вывести данные из объекта React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Всем привет, я только учу JS, React. Помогите советом.
Есть форма для заполнения данных об авто. Выглядит примерно вот так, данные  в carData.json

```
            <select
                name='carBrand'
                value={selectedBrand}
                onChange={handleBrandChange}
                className={style.select}
            >
                <option value='' disabled>
                    Выберите марку
                </option>
                {carData.map(car => (
                    <option key={car.id} value={car.id}>
                        {car.name}
                    </option>
                ))}
            </select>

            {selectedBrand && (
                <select
                    name='carModel'
                    value={selectedModel}
                    onChange={handleModelChange}
                    className={style.select}
                >
                    <option value='' disabled>
                        Выберите модель:
                    </option>
                    {carData
              .find((car) => car.id === selectedBrand)
              .models.map((model) => (
                <option key={model.id} value={model.id}>
                  {model.name}
                </option>
              ))}
                </select>
```

Можно ли написать такой же select, что бы в option был выбор года от начального до конечного ( 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001 ..., 2009). Объект выглядит так :

```
{
    "id": "BENTLEY",
    "name": "Bentley",
    "models": [
            {
        "id": "BENTLEY_ARNAGE",
        "name": "Arnage",
        "cyrillic-name": "арнаж",
        "class": "F",
        "yearFrom": 1998,
        "yearTo": 2009
    },
]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мы можем создать массив нужной нам длины и заполнить его датами. Дальше вы можете выполнить `map` по этому массиву и создать `option`

```js
const carData = {
  "yearFrom": 1998,
  "yearTo": 2009
};

const years = Array.from(
  {length: carData.yearTo - carData.yearFrom + 1},
  (_, index) => carData.yearFrom + index
);

console.info(years);
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, это очень помогло - Array.from(
  {length: carData.yearTo - carData.yearFrom + 1},
  (_, index) => carData.yearFrom + index
)